# Classification of Automorphism set of a Regular graph

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of an $r$-regular graph $G$ with $n$ vertices **(Not complete or cycle graph)** . Also, let $Aut(G)$ be the set of all its automorphisms (i.e.  set of permutation matrices).

So, if  $P_k \in Aut(G)$, then $P_k A P_k^{-1}=A$. 
Suppose the order of the group generated by a single element $P_k$ ( i.e $\langle P_k\rangle$ ) is $m_k$.

1. Does there always exist an unique $P_k$(except identity) of an unique order $O(n^k)$ where $k$ is a constant?
2. Does there always exist a polynomial size set of permutation matrices, which is a subset of $Aut(G)$ ,where  each permutation    $P_k$ , has  order $n^l$ where $l$ is a constant?

   *In  Strongly Regular Graph, Every automorphism has order at most $O(n^8)$. Does there  exist a polynomial size(i.e set size is at most $O(n^t)$) set where each element has order $n^l$ where $l$ is a constant?*
3. Can the automorphism set $Aut(G)$ be divided in to classes based on a certain “property” ( e.g. order of the group generated by single automorphism or eigenvalue etc) ?

   *[  For example, if every automorphism has different order then one can divide $Aut(G)$ in to total $|Aut(G)|$ sets/classes. If   elements of $Aut(G)$  have 2 order then   $Aut(G)$ can be divided into  2 classes . This kind of  classification is based on order . It could be based on something else. ]*
4. If (1),(2),(3) are not possible in general, is there a certain class of graph which follow any (1),(2),(3)?

For Strongly regular graph,there  is an upper bound on the order of automorphism [(see László Babai)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869314004967).

**Motivation:** *A graph isomorphism algorithm needs to  find 'compatible' set of automorphism. In an attempt, to decrease the number of possible candidates , above questions are asked.*

This post is partially motivated by [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124595/automorphism-group-of-regular-graph) query .

Comment: @DerekHolt , please see the link of L. Babai, it says, " In particular, we show that the order of every automorphism is $O(n^8)$", I am asking for regular graph  analogous  to Strongly regular graph.

Comment: For question$(3)$, always you can partition the automorphism group of any graph in two sets; odd permutations and even permutations.

Comment: @ShahroozJanbaz , yes, but the problem is, when you have an exponential size of automorphism set, this kind of partition does not  help much in decreasing  complexity of an algorithm unless one of the set has non exponential size (always).

Comment: So, please say your motivation directly. Maybe, we can say more by knowing your actual idea.

Comment: The answer to 1 is no, unless you count the identity element being the unique element of order $1$.

Comment: I still cannot really understand what you asking in 2. If there is no polynomial bound on the order of ${\rm Aut}(G)$, then clearly you cannot subdivide it into a polynomially bounded number of subsets each of polynomially bounded size.

Comment: @DerekHolt , 
Thanks for your response. In 2 ,I ask about existence of   a polynomial size set of permutation matrices, which is a subset of $Aut(G)$ ,where  each permutation    $P_k$ , has  order $n^l$ where $l$ is a constant, are you saying that  there is no such set when Aut(G) has exponential size?